# git commands not working when ran from a script

Tags: git, bash, shell, git-bash

I'm trying to run the bellow commands from a script:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add
```

The purpose behind them is to avoid being asked for my git passkey for the rest of the current session. Entering the commands one by one works ok and so I've put them in this script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add
```

After running it I get the correct response from git:

```
$ gitnopasskey.sh
Agent pid 4260
Enter passphrase for /u/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /u/.ssh/id_rsa (/u/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

but I'm still being prompted for my key everytime I fetch, pull etc. I've copied the commands used in the script and entered them one by one, to make sure I'm typing the same commands, but the result is the same - it works when entering the commands, it doesn't work when running them from a script.

Comment: Scripts run in their own shell. Try sourcing the script instead: `source gitnopasskey.sh`. Otherwise all environment variables will be untouched in your parent shell (just like `cd` inside a script won't touch your parent's working directory)

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts run in their own shell. Try sourcing the script instead:

```
source gitnopasskey.sh
```

Otherwise all environment variables will be untouched in your parent shell (just like cd inside a script won't touch your parent's working directory)